# Architecture - 2 foreign keys to same primary key?

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate, database-design, architecture

I'm having 2 tables, named `Teams` and `Matches` - I want to be able to add a `Match` which consist of 2 Teams, but also be able to get all the Matches for a specific `Team`.

What I can do is:

- A) Make a Many-to-Many relationship
  between the `Teams` and `Matches`
  table
- B) Make two extra columns in the
  `Matches` table named `HomeTeam` and
  `AwayTeam` which is foreign keys that
  refers to a Team in the `Teams`
  table.

We all agree on that **B** sounds best, since I know the exact amount of teams that will participate in a match everytime - right?

Now when it comes to declare this relationship in my entities, then I'll need to have 2 Many-to-one relationships to the `Match` entity, since the `Match` entity have 2 foreign keys that refers to a `Team` - and sine the number of foreign keys / references must be the same from both `Match` and `Team`, then I'll end up with something like this:

// Team.cs

```
public class Team
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; } 
    public virtual string TeamName { get; set; } 
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; } 
    public virtual IList<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; } 
    public virtual IList<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; } 
    public virtual IList<Match> Matches
    {
        get { return HomeMatches.Concat(AwayMatches).ToList(); }
    } 

    public Team()
    {
        HomeMatches = new List<Match>(); 
        AwayMatches = new List<Match>();
    }
}

public class TeamMap : ClassMap<Team>
{
    public TeamMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID); 
        Map(x => x.TeamName).Not.Nullable(); 
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID"); 
        HasMany(x => x.HomeMatches).KeyColumn("HomeTeamID").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); 
        HasMany(x => x.AwayMatches).KeyColumn("AwayTeamID").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); 

        Table("Teams");
    }
}
```

// Match.cs

```
public class Match
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; } 
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; } 
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; } 
    public virtual int WinnerID { get; set; } 
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; }
}

public class MatchMap : ClassMap<Match>
{
    public MatchMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID); 
        Map(x => x.WinnerID); 
        References(x => x.HomeTeam, "HomeTeamID"); 
        References(x => x.AwayTeam, "AwayTeamID"); 
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID"); 

        Table("Matches");
    }
}
```

As the code shows, then I'll have to use `.Concat()` to merge the HomeMatches and AwayMatches for a team, to get all the matches for a specific team..

Is this really the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B is the best way to go because A is a bit of a red herring.  You don't really want a many to many table between Matches and Teams but the reason you don't want them is not because you know the number of teams that will be in a match, but because a match is actually a many to many relationship already for team to team.

It just happens that in this case when you have a many to many relationship between two teams you call it a match and it has it's own set of properties (time, date, location...).

Match should definitely have two foreign keys to team as match is your many to many table.

Answer (score 2):

In a relational model it would look something like this. So two foreign keys is fine, the `HomeTeamID` and `AwayTeamID` are so called **role names**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may in fact be the best way to go.  I think you are just having a problem with the fact that you need to join two lists together to pull what seems to be a simple query.  However, the structure you are using isn't just relating the two teams, it is providing an almost-hierarchical structure, i.e. HomeTeam = Parent, AwayTeam = Child.

If you want to simply relate the two, you can create the Many-To-Many like you said:

```
[Team]

[MatchTeam]
TeamID
MatchID
IsHomeTeam

[Match]
```

Comment: thats what I thought too in the start... however I found it wrong to have a many-to-many relationship when only 2 teams can participate in a Match - and with a many-to-many I need to reinvent the wheel and figure out how to deal with such a case...

Comment: Exactly, which is why I think you already have the "best" way shown.

Comment: I guess my conern is whether the .Concat() is a perfomance drawback, when I have to merge the Home and Away Matches that a Team have played..

Comment: @ebb Performance should not be a problem. You might want to consider using a ReadOnlyCollection for the .Matches(), so that you will not be tempted to add something to that.